# Migrate data from one Google Analytics Property to Other

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

We by mistake created a Google Analytics Property of type Apps + Web(as in image). But it restricts us from using many Web specific features (like adding custom dimensions and connection with Google Tag Manager). 
[image]

So we create a new property of type Web (as we anyway won't need App related things anytime sooner), but now how can we migrate all analytics data(of 4-5 months) to the new property.

We tried to go through the docs and didn't find any related help.

Any input would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to migrate the data from one Account, web property or view in google analytics to another.  Once the data has been sent the data is there forever unless you delete the account.